# Adding AM/PM using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have simple code for 12hr format time

```
// This function gets the current time and injects it into the DOM
      function updateClock() {
                // Gets the current time
                var now = new Date();

                // Get the hours, minutes and seconds from the current time
                var hours = now.getHours();
                var minutes = now.getMinutes();
                var seconds = now.getSeconds();


                // Format hours, minutes and seconds
                if (hours > 12) {
                    hours = hours - 12;
                }
                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }

                // Gets the element we want to inject the clock into
                var elem = document.getElementById('clock');

                // Sets the elements inner HTML value to our clock data
                elem.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds ;
            }
```

I want to add AM/PM please help me thanks in advance
Im just beginner on javascript

Comment: Here's a hint: if you had to subtract 12 hours, then it's PM. Otherwise, it's AM.

Answer (score 3):

After editting your own code:

```
        // Get the hours, minutes and seconds from the current time
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();
        var amOrPm = 'AM';

        // Format hours, minutes and seconds
        if (hours > 12) {
            amOrPm = 'PM';
            hours = hours - 12;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        // Gets the element we want to inject the clock into
        var elem = document.getElementById('clock');

        // Sets the elements inner HTML value to our clock data
        elem.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + amOrPm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
```

then

```
elem.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
```

Comment: Its working now thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to code it by yourself, but there is a really really great library which handles everything with date stuff you can imagine.

Just checkout [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).
It's an easy AF lib to transform dates (also in pm/am).

If you've any question :) just comment ...